# Google Analytics Embedded Dashboard Filter

Tags: filter, google-analytics, dashboard

I want to filter the data being displayed on my google analytics dashboard. I have the dashboard embedded on my wordpress page. Some of the data coming through has a dimension value of '(not set)' and I want to remove that data from the view. Here is my code and I have labeled where I think the statement would go.

```
device = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
      reportType: 'ga',
      query: {
         'dimensions': 'ga:deviceCategory',
         'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
         'start-date': startDate,
         'end-date':endDate,
         'max-results': 6,
          sort: '-ga:sessions',
         /* FILTER CODE HERE */
      },
      chart: {
         type: 'TABLE',
         container: devicesCont,
         options: {width: '100%'}
      }
 });
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Read the descriptions of the tags!

Answer (score 0):

Your filter syntax would be the following

```
filter: 'ga:deviceCategory!=(not set)'
```

You can [test this query out](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3AdeviceCategory&sort=-ga%3Asessions&filters=ga%3AdeviceCategory!%3D(not%20set)&max-results=6) using the Query Explorer. And for future reference, check out the [filter syntax documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) on the Google Analytics developer site.